# Text being cut off from front for a particular font

Tags: android, fonts, textview

The first letter of each word on new line is cut off for **us denealian cursive font**.[image]

see the picture this one is with padding.If I am not using any padding ,it will be like in pic 2 [image]

This is my code

```
<com.font.anything.writinghelper
    android:id="@+id/textView" 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    android:text="japanese google donkey elephant ostrich"
    />
```

Here writing helper is a class extending textview just to underline the text

```
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Rect r = mRect;
    int padding =55;
    Paint paint = mPaint;
    int count = getLineCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    int baseline = getLineBounds(i, r);
    canvas.drawLine(r.left - padding, baseline, r.right + padding,
            baseline, paint);
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Can anyone help.?

**Edit**

Requested screenshot

[image]

Is There a way to put some extra space towards left side of the TextView ?

Comment: Can you sent me parameters of canvas.drawLine(r.left - padding, baseline, r.right + padding,
            baseline, paint);  this....

Comment: writing line helper is only for under lying the text I don't think it has something to do with this because I tried without the helper and the result was same .Any way this are the parameters

                mRect = new Rect();
  mPaint = new Paint();
  mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
  mPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
  mPaint.setColor(0xFF03B9FF);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I made a work around for this..It's a font issue and I am not sure it can be fixed by any other way.So what I have done is ,first get the TextView Layout and get the end and start of each line and hence obtain string in each line.Now append space in front of each line .Here is the entire code.May help someone else.

```
    ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> newLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line="";
    String text = getText().toString();
    Layout layout = getLayout();
    int start=0;
    int end;

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) {
        end = layout.getLineEnd(i);

        lines.add(text.substring(start,end));
        line = lines.get(i);
        start = end;
        String nwText = "";
        nwText = " "+ line+" ";
        newLines.add(nwText);
    }
    Paint mPaint = getPaint();
    int i = 0;
   // String[] textLines = Results.split("\\n+");
    //float textsize = getTextSize();

    for (String textLine : newLines)
    {
       // mPaint.setTextSize(textsize);
        int baseline = getLineBounds(i, r);
        canvas.drawText(textLine, 0, baseline, mPaint);
       i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I come out with a similar solution. This recursively add spaces to the beginning and end of line, and if while adding space the word go to the line below this solution fix itself errors.
(The firsts 3 variables have class scope).

```
    row = 0;
    offset = 0;
    oldPos = -1;
    final String nonBreakingSpace = "\u00A0\u00A0";
    textV.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int pos;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(textV.getText());

            pos = textV.getLayout().getLineStart(row);
            if (oldPos!=-1 && pos<oldPos)
            {
                sb.delete(oldPos, oldPos + nonBreakingSpace.length());
            }

            if (offset==0)
            {
                row++;
                offset = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                offset = 0;
            }
            final int lineCount = textV.getLayout().getLineCount();
            pos = textV.getLayout().getLineStart(row);
            oldPos = pos+offset;
            if (row>=lineCount)
            {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                    removeLayoutListenerPre16(textV.getViewTreeObserver(), this);
                } else {
                    removeLayoutListenerPost16(textV.getViewTreeObserver(), this);
                }
                sb.insert(0, nonBreakingSpace);
                sb.insert(sb.length(), nonBreakingSpace);
            }
            else
            {
                sb.insert(pos+offset, nonBreakingSpace);                    
            }
            textV.setText(sb);
        }
    });
```

and:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void removeLayoutListenerPre16(ViewTreeObserver observer, OnGlobalLayoutListener listener){
    observer.removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(listener);
}

@TargetApi(16)
private void removeLayoutListenerPost16(ViewTreeObserver observer, OnGlobalLayoutListener listener){
    observer.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(listener);
}
```